Bevel modifier causes shading issue
I was using a Boolean modifier with a cube as a cutter for a cylinder. When The bevel modifier causes a shading problem coming from the beveled corners. I've already tried adding loopcuts to isolate the area, but it didn't help.




If you want to keep the modifier, create this edge loop and it will prevent the bad shape:

Or apply the modifier and create this topology:

